# How to write two inner join for Rails Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to write a rails active record query for this SQL query:

```
SELECT c.name FROM categories as c where c.id IN (select c.parent_id FROM categories as c join categories_coaches as cc on c.id=cc.category_id where cc.coach_id=17 group by c.parent_id)
```

Models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :coaches
end

class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Comment: Can you please show the Models with the associations and explain what you want to achieve with the query?

Comment: @EgonWilzer i edited my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey try in this way**

```
categories = Category.where(:id => Category.joins(:coaches).where("coaches.id = ?", 17).group(:parent_id).map(&:parent_id))
```

Comment: Thanks @Vishal JAIN it is working... thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions propose use of array operations, which is not a good idea.

You don't actually need grouping and subquerying. The same result can be obtained by rewriting your query to the following form:

```
SELECT categories.* FROM categories 
INNER JOIN categories c2 ON c2.parent_id = categories.id
INNER JOIN categories_coaches cc ON c2.id = cc.category_id
WHERE cc.coach_id = 17
```

Which translates into `ActiveRecord` this way:

```
Category.joins('INNER JOIN categories c2 ON c2.parent_id=categories.id')
        .joins('INNER  JOIN categories_coaches cc ON c2.id = cc.category_id')
        .where('cc.coach_id = ?', 17)
```

Comment: here it is fetching two times the same result

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try this:

```
items = Category.joins(:coaches).where("caoches.coach_id = ?", 17).group(:parent_id).pluck(:parent_id)
categories = Category.where (id: items)
```

Comment: Hey as per model structure i don't think their is coach_id in caoches table as in your query.